# Extracting a string pattern from a file

Tags: linux, unix

```
http://www.keshav.com/hack-public/hms/pick400/Seg_1/pick400_1079.tk
http://www.keshav.com/hack-public/hms/pick400/Seg_1/pick400_1080.tk
```

how to extract only the last word of the url "pick400_***". I need output in the following format

```
pick400_1079.tk
pick400_1080.tk
```

Comment: is it for a linux script or are you coding in some programming language?

Comment: hi ...i am using unix scripting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' inFile
```

Comment: awk makes use of a file...i dont want a file here...the results are displayed on a screen. I need to take them from screen and display the same on the screen.

Comment: `awk makes use of a file`: I think you have some misconception. You can use awk like this also: `echo 'http://www.keshav.com/hack-public/hms/pick400/Seg_1/pick400_1079.tk' | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you might do it in `bash`:

```
while read line; do
  basename $line;
done < inputfile
```

Alternatively,

```
while read line; do
  echo ${line##*/};
done < inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's=.*/==' INPUT
```